# How to approach relationship between prices in two different years of many different products?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am currently working through a workbook that is supposed to help me 'ease' into R (I've used SPSS before). However, there are some questions I am having a hard time with regardless of the program. I'm not very experienced with multiple regression etc and am finding it difficult to understand what it is that I am supposed to be doing. The examples are unrelated to my field, which makes me doubt myself a lot.

One of the examples asks me to analyse the relationship between prices of different products taken from two years. Let's say 20 different chocolate brands and the price they were sold at in the years 2000 and 2010. 
My problem is that I don't really know where to start. I understand that I have continuous data (prices), a category1 (year) and another category2 (brands). I want to see the relationship between the continuous data and the category1 for the different categories2.

That's about as far as I get. I'm thinking multiple regression? But then again, are the prices of the years causal? Sorry, this is just really nothing I'd normal work at.

A hint in the right direction would be very much appreciated. I still want to try and write the R code myself as this is what I actually want to practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a paired data question. Not knowing how prices are supposed to change, I would do a [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test), which would tell you whether the prices have changed or not. What else do you want to know?